# Different Switch Intents In ExpandableListView Parents - Previous One Doesn't Work

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-listview, expandablelistview

I'm trying to create an ExpandibleListView with intents that switch to new classes. When using only one switch, there is no problem, but when I want different parents to switch diffent classes, only one of them works, the other one stays like empty (Its arrows turn up and down but nothing happens). How can I make them work together?

Here is my codes:

ExpandibleListAdapter.java

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String,List<String>> listHashMap;



    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this.listHashMap = listHashMap;
    }



    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return listDataHeader.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
        return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).get(i1); //  i = group item , i1= ChildItem

    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return i1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup ViewGroup) {
        String headerTitle = (String)getGroup(i);
        if(view == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group,null);
        }
        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
        return view;

        }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup ViewGroup) {
        final String childText = (String)getChild(i,i1);
        if(view == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
        }
        TextView txtListChild = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
        {


private ExpandableListView listView;
private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
private List<String> listDataHeader;
private HashMap<String,List<String>> listHash;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    listView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    initData();
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this,listDataHeader,listHash);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    
}

private void initData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    listHash = new HashMap<>();

    listDataHeader.add("Line One");
    listDataHeader.add("Line Two");
    


    List<String> genel = new ArrayList<>();
**//The problem starts here**

    listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            final String selected = (String) listAdapter.getGroup(groupPosition);
            Intent intent;

            switch (selected) {
                case "Line One":
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LineOne.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }
            return false; //return true doesn't let the other parents to open.
        }
    });


    List<String> terims = new ArrayList<>();
    listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            final String terims = (String) listAdapter.getGroup(groupPosition);
            Intent niyet;//I used "intent" instead of "niyet" as same above but nothing has changed.

            switch (terims) {
                case "Line Two":
                    niyet = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LineTwo.class);
                    startActivity(niyet);
                    break;
            }
            return false; 
        }
    });
    


    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(0),genel);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(1),terims);
    
    

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set 2 OnGroupClickListeners. The second one cancels the first one. You should set one listener and then check for both sets of conditions in the one listener.

Comment: Thank you so much, I replaced the second switch case into the first onGroupClick and the both work. God bless you <3